# How to use openid selector in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, openid-selector

How to use [openid selector javascript API](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) in java? I have seen openid4java but that is not what I want. I need the same interface as given by openid selector.

Can you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

So you want a client-side (swing, applet) openId library for Java? I don't think there is one, because it does not make sense for it to exist - openId is used in web environments (it redirects back to a url, which is not a concept of desktop applications)

If you, on the other hand, want a JSP taglib or a JSF component for that - no, there isn't. But you should be able to use the openid-selector easily with those technologies.

Comment: @Anand - what is your case? a desktop app (with a server-side), a webapp? What server side code do you want - a jsp taglib, a jsf component? another framework?

Comment: @Bozho: my case is that of a webapp. The server side is in java servlets & front end html/javascript

Comment: @Anand - well, then use the javascript openid-selector and use it in your JSP. What stops you from doing that? (I have used it in the same way in the same scenario)

Comment: @Bozho: I see the following in the JS file of openid selector:  <form id="openid_form" action="/some/auth.jsp" method="post"> What should be my code in the file "auth.jsp"?

Comment: @Anand - there you will have to use the openid4jara. Take a look at the example code there.